# Suggested Diet. Is my personal trainer trying to kill me?

Tags: diet

I'm a newbie at the gym, I've been training for 4 months now.

I bought the whole package at the gym, so I have a personal trainer and a nutritionist.
The thing is that I'm skinny, I'm 1.83m (6") tall and I started weighting 73 Kg (160.9 lb) we started cutting, down for body fat, I ate about ~1800 cals/day; I was loosing weight and fat at the same time, my muscle index was slowly (very very slowly) getting better.

I train 5 days a week, for about 1:45 mins: 10 mins warming, 1 hour of lifting and 15 minutes of light cardio at the end.

Now we're achieving for body weight gain (bulking) and the first diet cycle I lost weight and muscle. My calorie intake is about ~2400 cal. Now I weight 70 Kg (154 lb) which worries me.

I was not happy with the results of my first bulking diet and I felt like I was loosing too much weight after those months, my jeans no longer fit me and I feel skinnier.

My whole goal is to fit better into clothes, I'm too big for small size and to skinny for medium size, and I'm tired of that. Well, at least I was, last time I bought clothes (this weekend) I had to buy small sizes, now I fit in them... that's what triggered my frustration.

My Personal trainer happens to be a nutritionist too, I communicated my frustration, and he suggested I followed a diet he'll build for me, the result is totally opposite of my previous nutritionist ideas, it goes as this (5-meal based):

Meal 1:

- 8 egg whites cooked with onion and tomato.
- 2 slices of bread (toasted if you like).
- 1 cop of green tea or coffee (no sugar).

Post workout:

- 500ml protein milkshake

Meal 2:

- 250g (8oz) of chicken breast.
- 2 roasted medium nopales with purple onion.
- 1 cup of rice.

Meal 3:

- 250g (8oz) of beef steak.
- 1 potato.
- 1 tortilla.
- 1 little cup of light fruit based jelly.

Meal 4:

- 250g (8oz) of fish (tuna or tilapia)
- 1 plate of lettuce, tomato and cucumber.
- 2 nopal toasts.

Meal 5:

- 250g (8oz) of chicken breast.
- 1 plate of 2 nopales and white onion.
- 1 medium pice of arabic bread.

I'm worried about the huge amount of meat there is in this plan, 1 daily kilogram. Also there are no fruits nor legumes as they were on my previous diets.

Is my personal trainer right or should I talk to him (or complete ditch him and stick to the previous nutritionist)? I don't think the diet is healthy.

Comment: This seems rather restrictive for a weight gaining diet. You also don't *need* to eat 5 meals per day. Since you're bulking (actually regardless of bulking or cutting) feel free to eat more fruits and legumes (if cutting just pay attention to total calorie consumption). If you *are* losing weight while "bulking" then you need to eat even more than what you are now.

Comment: It's easier if you choose foods that are more energy dense (relatively high calories for small serving sizes). Some examples include peanut butter, whole eggs (yolks not removed), full-fat dairy, and grains (oats, pasta, rice, etc).

Comment: If I were you, I'd check your trainer's credentials.  Is he certified from a reputable organization?

Answer (score 2):

I used to weigh 62kg before I started training and dieting, and I now weigh 87kg. Let me just start by telling you that this is your life now. It's hard at first, but you get used to it.

Dieting to gain weight is something people think is easy, because we've all heard the complaints from people trying to lose weight. They have to go hungry all the time, and eat small portions of boring food.

Well, for those of us who want to GAIN weight, we have to eat lots of food, even when we're not hungry, and eat until we're stuffed and then continue a bit more. Same same, just opposite.

Yes, it's going to be hard. Just as hard as those people who complain about wanting to lose weight. But the diet seems perfectly healthy.

**Warning**

You say that your PT is a "nutritionist". This is a huge red flag! I am also a nutritionist. I have NO education in the field, but I am a nutritionist. This is something anyone can call themselves, because "nutritionist" is not a protected title.

In English, the title of "dietitian" is protected. It implies education and graduation in the field of nutrition and regulation of diet.

Since your name looks hispanic, I'm going to assume that you live in a Spanish-speaking country (and I apologize if this is wrong). You have to find out which title is protected in your country. If you DO live in the US or another English speaking country, then I'm sorry for bringing this up. Then it's simply nutritionist (bad) and dietitian (good).

Comment: I got confused by the term. Both of the people I called nutritionist are dietitians then. Thanks for the motivation and the info :)